# Athena/SQL query to get the desired result

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, subquery, presto, amazon-athena

**sample_input_table**

```
user  name  action      date
 1    aaa    view      2020-09-03
 2    bbb    view      2020-09-02
 3    ccc    view      2020-08-28
 4    ddd    view      2020-08-25
 1    aaa    purchase  2020-09-09
```

I have a table with huge number of rows, the table looks like above.

**question**

1. i want to print the rows which have `purchase` action and
2. at the same time, the user who did `purchase` must have row with `view` action
3. and at the same time, that `view` action will be in the date range of purchase_date(`2020-09-09`) and  purchase_date - 7days(`2020-09-02`).

**I want to achieve these 3 point in one sql query**

**sample_output**

```
user  name  action      date
1    aaa    purchase  2020-09-09
```

if we see sample output from the sample input

1. our end result have only purchase_events
2. purchased_user had a row with `view` action
3. and that `view` was there in the timeframe of `2020-09-09` and  `2020-09-02`(purchased_date, purchased_date - 7 days)

**Can anyone suggest some solution for this?**

Comment: MySQL or Athena? Please tag only one database.

Comment: sorry, its athena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.action = 'purchase' and exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.user = t.user 
        and t1.action = 'view'
        and t1.date >= t.date - interval '7' day
        and t1.date < t.date
    )
```

Comment: Hi GMB,  Can you please explain it.

Comment: @siva: `exists` checks if another row exists with a the same user and a "view" action within the last 7 days.

Comment: Thanks GMB.

Just one more question, can we achieve the same solution with JOINS as well ? If yes, can you please tell me how?

Comment: @siva: joins are not really appropriate here. If there are multiple matching views, it will duplicate the originating purchase row. For what you want, `exists` is the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions.  Assuming "purchase" is the last state:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'purchase' then date end) over (partition by user) as purchase_date,
             max(case when action = 'view' then date end) over (partition by user) as max_view_date             
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'purchase' and
      max_view_date >= purchase_date - interval '7 day';
```